# CSS grid: element resizes when content is put into in

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-grid

I am working on a simple tic-tac-toe app with react and I have this problem. When content/text changes inside element it stretches its height, but when all 3 rows have content inside it sets back to normal. Thank you in advance.

link to this project: https://codepen.io/Hakor/pen/LYdorey

my CSS:

```
.main-container{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.square{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 64px;
}
```

Comment: You can use `line-height` and set it to `0px`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding an [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) and maintain the square!

```
.square{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 64px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/kai1992cool/pen/abYrKjp)

Comment: @Hakor does this answer solve your issue completely?

Comment: yes this solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, I would use this one:

```
.main-container{
    grid-auto-rows: 33%;
}
```

After that you may set additional 'gap' in .main-container to align your table or 'justify-content'.

Hope this helps! Regards,

Comment: better use `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;`